# Loss doesn't decrease when I apply a nn model in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using a toy model to predict a feature called `Probability` from a dataset which has almost 30 features. And I apply a toy model and `nn.MSELoss()`, trying to fit the model with the dataset. However,  I found the loss didn't decrease.

The model is quite simple, which codes are listed below.

```
class Logistic(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size=1):
        super(Logistic, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.output = 0
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(input_size, output_size)
        self.activation = nn.Sigmoid()
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layer1(x)
        x = self.activation(x)
        return x
```

And I used `Dataset` and `DataLoader` to read the DataFrame format of my dataset. Also, I trained my model in GPU.

```
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
total_epoch = 50
logi = Logistic(len(valuable_col) - 1, 1)
logi.to(device)
lr = 100

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(logi.parameters(), lr=lr)
train_loss = []
valid_loss = []

logi.double()

for epoch in range(total_epoch):
    logi.train()
    train_loss_ = 0
    for data_, target_ in tqdm.tqdm(train_loader):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        data_, target_ = data_.to(device), target_.to(device)
        
        output = logi.forward(data_)
        loss = criterion(output, (target_).long())
        train_loss_ += loss.item()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    train_loss.append(train_loss_ / len(train_loader))
    
    logi.eval()
    valid_loss_ = 0
    for data_, target_ in tqdm.tqdm(test_loader):
        data_, target_ = data_.to(device), target_.to(device)
        
        output = logi.forward(data_)
        valid_loss_ += criterion(output, target_)
    valid_loss.append(valid_loss_.item() / len(test_loader))
    print("[Epoch: %d] train_loss: %.6f, valid_loss: %.6f" % ((epoch + 1, train_loss[-1], valid_loss[-1])))
```

I found the loss is almost the same in each epoch. I can not figure out why. And this make me confused.

Comment: dont you think you set your learning rate a bit too high? 100! is too much normally. and it could be youre ossiliating all the time . try decreasing it to like 0.1 and so and see how that goes

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention that I try learning rate as 10, 1, 0.1, 0.01 etc. But the loss stops to change. Therefore I try to increase my learning rate but still get nothing.

Comment: try with ```lr = 0.001`` also, try to increase the dataset size. Also, I will suggest you to use the LogisticRegression model from sklearn because it has regularization and other stuff implemented in the backend. In this case, your code is more of a neural network than a Logistic Regression model.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience in such cases it usually comes down to either your model being to small for the data, or something is wrong with your data. It is very important to make sure that you are definitely feeding the network the inputs you think you are feeding.

Time and time again it boils down to something being twisted in the data pipeline (eg. no adequate normalization, label/data mismatch...). Another good sanity check is to see whether you can overfit on a single batch or sample.

If you want a very practical guide to setting up neural nets I highly recommend [this blogpost](http://karpathy.github.io/2019/04/25/recipe/) by Andrej Karpathy, which I keep coming back to after years of experience still.

Comment: Thanks! I will try further to solve this problem! Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Sure, let us know once you found the culprit!